# How can I get all objects I can write to

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Let's say I have a class Post, which is shared by some users.

In creation I set the post's ACL to allow public reading, but writing only for some Roles.

How can I query all the posts I can write to?

**Example**

My user belongs to the role `A` and `B`.

How can I query all posts that can be written by roles `A` or `B`?

Comment: If you have given `Write` permissions only, then your user cannot query the records as it obviously requires `Read` permissions.

Comment: If you don't have `Read` permissions, they can't GET them. Read means to pull/get, write means to change.

Comment: This OP doesn't mention read permission.  I think its fair to assume the intent is universal read, and write limited to a few roles.

Comment: I added the read information. As danh pointed, the class is publicly readable, but only some roles can write to it.